# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying to setup selenium grid. and follow the following steps:-

1) **Start hub on Windows 10 (32 bit) :-**
java -jar "path to standalone jar" -role hub -port 4444

2) **Start node on Ubuntu14.04 (64 bit) :-**
java -jar "path to standalone jar" -role webdriver -port 5555 -hub "http:// ip of windows PC:4444/grid/hub"

The node and hub started successfully. But the problem  is when I am trying to execute the following script it throws exception "         org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session" Please look at the following code:-

```
public class gridclass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","Path to/geckodriver");
    WebDriver wd=null;
    try
    {   
        DesiredCapabilities desire = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        wd = new RemoteWebDriver( new URL("http://path to hub URL/grid/hub"), desire);
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    wd.get("http://www.google.com");
    wd.close();
    wd.quit();
 }
}
```

The above code I have written on Windows 10 (i.e on hub machine). Is that the correct way?

If it the correct  and code is correct then how to solve org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException.
 Please help me in this case.

Comment: The geckodriver property needs to be specified on the machine where it is executed. What happens if you start the node using `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER -jar "path to standalone jar" -role webdriver -port 5555 -hub "http://IP_OF_WINDOWS_PC:4444/grid/hub"`?

Comment: I tried but it give me same result. Please correct me if I m wrong. What I have done is I create hub and node and write down the script on hub and try to execute on node. Is that the correct approach.

Comment: The approach is generally not bad. You can execute your script on any machine as long as it has network connection to the hub machine. I noticed two more things in the node's command. The hub should end in /grid/register and not in /grid/hub, and the role should be node, not webdriver. So the correct command should be something like java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER -jar "path to standalone jar" -role node -port 5555 -hub "http://IP_OF_WINDOWS_PC:4444/grid/register" Do you get any errors after that in the output of node/hub when executing the script?

Comment: Yes I got the same error. I have also tried to create session manually. but it says Unable to create new session. I googled this problem but couldnot found any fix

Comment: I mean the output of the node/hub in the command line. When you execute the script, do you see any extra output from these java processes?

Comment: Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.112:4444/grid/register
The node is registered to the hub and ready to use

Comment: It says:Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.112:4444/grid/register
 The node is registered to the hub and ready to use

Comment: @GouravShivalkar - Run your sample code and share the node console output. The node console output should tell you what exactly went wrong. Also just to rule out any discrepancies with Firefox (FF support is undergoing a bit of a transformation in the Selenium world) what happens when you try with Chrome ?